# Changed ssh AllowUsers option and lost access to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I was trying to create sftp user on ubuntu 14.04 server, I updated sshd_config AllowUsers option to include the name of the sftp user, however, this restricted the access to only this user via sftp, and I lost access to all other users via ssh, including the root.

The server is a dedicated server that is owned by my company, is there anyway to login to the server via ssh using any other user??

Comment: If one of the users you added belonged to the  `sudo` group then you can `sudo -i` to the root account and repair `sshd_config` otherwise prepare for the trip to your company premises

Comment: Another way to get root access is to use `su -` and if you know root's password then you can fix this problem